# What is a good way to index for such a query?

Tags: sql, sql-server, optimization, indexing, sql-like

Jeff mentions in https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/03/redesigned-users-page/ that

> - Searches are “match anywhere” again, but the minimum match is now 3 characters.

Excellent stuff! This was "broken" for quite a while due to the performance of a LIKE match, and the fact that fulltext searching is inexactl (for example, initials in a user name would be too short to feature in any fulltext index).

There must be a way to to this and I have an idea, but I would like to see if anyone already has a solution (alternative) for this challenge.

Sample query:

```
SELECT TOP 36 *
FROM users
WHERE nickname LIKE '%' + @search + '%'
```

**Note:** even though the tag is sql-server due to maximum of 5 tags, I am more than happy to investigate solutions in other RDBMS for portability.

Comment: Have you seen this? http://www.sommarskog.se/yourownindex.html The book seams to cover your query in the chapter "Build your own index".

Comment: @Mik - Yes I know of the book. I should add **if you have read it, please do not post the content here**. Buy it for a good cause. I'm looking for self-conceived or "open"-sourced ideas. The book information is not free

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Postgres at least recently added [a trigram-matching solution](http://www.depesz.com/index.php/2011/02/19/waiting-for-9-1-faster-likeilike/) to its standard modules. It rewrites a LIKE query into multiple trigram-matching queries. Unfortunately, the index sizes tend to be huge.

There is also [Wildspeed](http://www.sai.msu.su/~megera/wiki/wildspeed), which also suffers from huge indices. I guess the size depends much on column length.

Comment: +1 Very useful. The note about index size explosion was expected.

Comment: SQL Server now builds string indexes like the trigrams in Postgresql. This answer helped me find the correct references/search terms.